# Proof of Pascal' identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

The identity 
$$\binom{x+1}{k}-\binom{x}{k}=\binom{x}{k-1}$$
is claimed to hold (using the binomial polynomials, considered as lying in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$) for $k$ at least $1$.
Proof: by the usual Pascal identity it holds for all $x=n$ at least $k$ and hence (using that these are polys of the same degree?) we can conclude (?) that these must be equal as polynomials.

Is my proof ok?

Comment: What does "it holds for all $x=n$ at least $k$" mean?

Comment: the identity whose validity is asserted. well formally I mean if you evaluate these polynomials at integers at least $k$ then they are equal.

Comment: Note that $\binom xk$ is a $k$-degree polynomial, while $\binom x{k-1}$ is a $k-1$-degree polynomial...

Comment: @abiessu: yes I am saying that the right hand side and left hand side have the same degree.

Comment: Why don't you use the factorial definitions to sort it out?

Comment: @abiessu: if you do it then it gets a mess

Comment: Actually, it's pretty easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea goes through nicely. Let
$$P(x)=\binom{x+1}{k}-\binom{x}{k}-\binom{x}{k-1}.$$
Then $P(x)$ is the zero polynomial or a polynomial of degree $\le k$.

By the usual combinatorial argument, we have $P(x)=0$ for $x=k, k+1, \dots, 2k$.  Since a non-zero polynomial of degree $\le k$ over a field has at most $k$ zeros, it follows that $P(x)$ is the zero polynomial.

More briefly, the equation $P(x)=0$ has infinitely many zeros, so $P(x)$ is the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

To show:

$$\binom{x+1}{k}-\binom{x}{k}=\binom{x}{k-1}$$

In factorial form, we have

$$\frac {(x+1)!}{k!(x+1-k)!}-\frac {x!}{k!(x-k)!}=\frac {x!}{(k-1)!(x-k+1)!}$$

Working with just the LHS,

$$\begin{align}\frac {(x+1)!}{k!(x+1-k)!}-\frac{x-k+1}{x-k+1}\frac {x!}{k!(x-k)!}&=\frac {x!}{(k-1)!(x-k+1)!}\\
\frac {(x+1)x!}{k!(x+1-k)!}-\frac {(x-k+1)x!}{k!(x-k+1)!}&=\frac {x!}{(k-1)!(x-k+1)!}\\
\frac {kx!}{k!(x+1-k)!}&=\frac {x!}{(k-1)!(x-k+1)!}\\
\frac {x!}{(k-1)!(x+1-k)!}&=\frac {x!}{(k-1)!(x-k+1)!}\end{align}$$

Not messy at all... `</tongue-in-cheek>`.

Comment: well the argument is just ugly and the ideas lack any elegance. I know that it is trivial, but I certainly consider it messy

Comment: I respect your opinion, although I disagree that there is a lack of elegance.  There is certainly a different type of elegance about the proof in words as demonstrated in the answer above by @AndréNicolas.  To me, this way has a more "direct" elegance to it, which is to say that it goes directly to the definitions and the result is immediate...